# Two-column layout with CSS: Last div on left to fill remaining area

Tags: css, layout

I have a two column layout. When the two columns are of equal height, or the left column is longer, then it [looks pretty good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdYk1.png). But if the left column is [short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pn6t.png), then I have a bunch of empty dark space that [looks ugly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siymc.png).

Is there a CSS trick to "make the last box on the page fill the remaining space"?

I know it's a fairly regular question and I know of some ways to make a single element fill its container, but I've never heard of a way to only make the last element fill remaining space.

So far my ideas are to use images to create the look on the left so it can just extend all the way down as a background, or to use Javascript to compute the height dynamically. Images are not ideal because that would limit customizations somewhat and this page needs to be as easily customizable as possible. And I'm afraid using Javascript will result in noticeable "jerkyness" whenever you load a short page.

Comment: Simple answer, no. Extensive answer, there are workarounds but they will likely involve heavy modification of your core html/css layout. Give us what you already have and maybe someone can figure out a solution that works for you.

Comment: The HTML or CSS doesn't matter because I can completely change it if I need to (the product is not released yet). So if there's a way, then all I need is an example.

Answer (score 1):

The only easy way to do this is with [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/). Basically, you make your background image look like your column.

Comment: Nice technique. The problem I see with his layout, is that his left box has a shadowed bottom border which cannot be repeated vertically. So, if he uses your solution, then he will need to put an additional absolute positioned image on the bottom of the page, to contour the bottom shade of the box.

Comment: This is the background idea I mentioned. I can make it work but because of the design it will be a bit messy (because of problems like Jose mentioned). The bigger problem is that it affects the customizability of the templates, and that is the primary objective for the design. So I was hoping to avoid it if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the last element on the left column all the way down, you can use an absolute positioned element with an anchor on bottom:

```
#leftCol {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

This ensures `#leftCol` is always attached to the bottom.

[jsFiddel here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/gshFK/)

Comment: No and no, you're guessing, how can you know that this will work? You can't because you don't have his html/css to look at. Guess #1 will fail because if you absolutely position it it will snap only to the bottom if you only specify the bottom. Guess #2 will create other problems since I doubt his leftcol has an absolute height that fills the left area.

Comment: Guess #1 - if he wants the left column all the way down, then `bottom: 0px` (or 10px, 100px, or whatever bottom) must be specified.

Comment: I can make things work with just one box (i.e., just one #leftCol). But the problem is when there's more than one box. Imagine two #leftCols, one below the other, and you only want the second one to "stretch" down to the bottom. Other than tables, I don't know of a way.

Comment: @ChristopherNadeau In case of two `#leftCols`, you cannot use the same `id` for both, you should use, for instance, `#leftCol1` and `#leftCol2` (or instead, use a class for both `.leftCols`) and then simply apply the css to the column id you want stretched all the way down

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how high the first `#leftCols` is on the page, so I can't absolutely position the last block. In other words, I can't know the `top` of the last block to absolutely position it, and I don't know what it's `height` should be either so I can't use just `bottom`.

Comment: I have added another elegant solution, on a separated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-height: 100%` for the last left column

See solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/bKGPv/)